# XFS won't mount with fstab options in Fedora 12

Tags: linux, boot, mount, fedora, xfs

Okay, the topic says it all. I used the usual 'mkfs.xfs -l size=128m,lazy-count=1 /dev/sdX' at creation. After that, I would like to use custom mount options like: 
This goes instead of the "defaults" part in /etc/fstab

> noatime,nobarrier,logbsize=256k,logbufs=8,biosize=16

I receive the following error at boot: INVALID log iosize 4 [not 12-30] << No one used iosize 4... what does it mean? Maybe it is connected to the options..but which one? (At the minute I'm usig it with: noatime,nobarrier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was the "biosize" part. Fstab options: noatime,nobarrier,logbufs=8,logbsize=256k .. Works flawless. Had to download kernel-docs and check the xfs.txt in filesystems/ folder.